# Player de Vídeo online que rode arquivos de vídeo .mkv e .mp4

Tags: html5, flash

Gostaia de saber se existe algum plugin de player de vídeo on online que tenha como rodar online arquivos de mkv e mp4 com URLs de arquivos direto do servidor já tentei o JWPlayer o DIVX Web vídeo o primeiro só aceita Mp4 o segundo nem funciona se o usuário não tiver DivX instalado no pc.

**Alguém a conhece algum plugin de vídeo player online mesmo que seja em HTML5 que rode esses dois formatos.**

Answer (score 0):

Funciona com links de vídeos em servidores particulares ou do VIMEO.
Youtube funcionava mas começou a apresentar bloqueios do próprio Youtube.

Para carregar os vídeos, basta editar as configurações do formato do player e os endereços dos vídeo em arquivo XML. O download do player grátis pode ser feito no site do desenvolvedor: https://www.hdwplayer.com/.

Se servir para suas necessidades, vale a pena comprar a licença PRO e colocar sua logomarca

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o https://videojs.com/

Ele é muito bom e possui uma documentação bem completa.

Um exemplo de implementação, retirado da própria página do videojs:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0.3/video.js"></script>
</body>
```